# Error NULL DEFAULT NULL Laravel migration with MariaDB

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration, mariadb

I have the following migration, where I'm adding an extra column in a table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddTenantIdToPeopleTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        /*
        * Need to create the column as null and then mark it as non-null to
        * avoid SQLite problem General error: 1 Can not add to NOT NULL column with default value NULL
        */

        Schema::table('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('tenant_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->index('tenant_id');
        });

        Schema::table('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('tenant_id')->nullable(false)->change();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
            Schema::table('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->dropColumn('tenant_id');
            });
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}
```

I can run this migration with PostgreSQL, SQLite and MySQL without any errors, but when I try to run with Maria DB, this error happens:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY3Q5.jpg)

I tried some things but nothing works.

Comment: You've already got existing data in that column that is `NULL`. Maria DB does not want the `NULL` value if you're not going to have a `nullable` column. Any reason you don't want it to be nullable?

Comment: No particular reason. I manage to do this way with postgres, mysql and sqlite, but mariaDB is giving me a hard time. Is there any way to make this works?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this thing working. 
I just added the "->default(null)"

I did this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('tenant_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->index('tenant_id');
        });

        Schema::table('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('tenant_id')->nullable(false)->default(null)->change();
        });
    }
```